# Hölder-like inequality $\|f\|_\pi\|g\|_\infty\le\frac{1}{16}\|f\|_\pi^2+4\|g\|_\infty^2$

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, parameter-estimation, matrix-norms, holder-inequality

I don't know how the second bound occurs. It's not Hölder, Cauchy-Schwarz or Minkowsi.

[image: 2nd inequality]

Of course we have:

[image: pi-norm]

It appears in the following paper on page 531:
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-13/issue-2/Penalized-nonparametric-mean-square-estimation-of-the-coefficients-of-diffusion/10.3150/07-BEJ5173.full

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [Peter-Paul inequality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Young%27s_inequality_for_products#/Elementary_case):
$$
ab \le \frac{a^2}{2\epsilon} + \frac{\epsilon b^2}{2}
$$
with $\epsilon = 8$.